# Deploying standard picklists via Metadata API

Tags: metadata, picklist, jenkins

Have some trouble deploying leadSource and Industry picklists via Metadata API.   Had to comment out both of them from the build.  It may have something to do with these picklists being shared by multiple objects, I don't know.   We are using Jenkins for the deployment.  Here is a sample deployment error:

```
Error: objects/Lead.object(1150,13):An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1967816892-11483 (1554758315)
```

Comment: Can you share the values you were trying to deploy? Maybe something was malformed or too long?

Comment: Please post your findings as an answer and not as an update to your question; this will help maintain the Q&A format and assist future visitors with finding the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, we figured it out by trial and error, didn't see it documented anywhere.

There are some standard picklists that are shared by multiple objects: "Lead Source", "Account Source", and "Industry".

For example, "Lead Source" field is on Contact, CampaignMember, Lead, Opportunity, and Account. Although on Account it's named differently ("Account Source"), the picklist values are shared by all of these objects. To deploy this picklist, we need to make sure that we only list it on one of these objects, and comment it out from the others, otherwise we get a build error.

Currently our build is set up as follows:

1) "Lead Source" field is deployed via "Account Source" field on the Account object, from where the picklist values are copied by Salesforce automatically to four other objects.

2) Industry field is deployed via Account object. It is commented out on the Lead object. From Account, SF automatically makes these picklist values available on the Lead.

3) The Lead's name field is actually a composition of several other fields including the "Salutation" picklist (Miss, Mr., etc.). Bizarrely to deploy that you need to deploy the CampaignMember.Salutation field

Comment: Hi,  1) Above. I tried to deploy Account, Contact and Opportunity objects but note that the picklist values for LeadSource or AccountSource are not included in any of the 3 objects. How can I ensure the picklist values within the field are retrieved when retrieving the metadata via ANT. I'm pretty sure I had not seen this issue before, or maybe I just did not come across it before.   Thanks for any help.